# Python beyond face recognition

Tags: python, detect

I am trying to figure out (for a project) if Python (or others) could recognize different objects in movement. For example, with a phone camera could possible to count how many chickens pass in front of the app/cam?.

Thank you guys

Comment: you could learn that from examples of the most popular frameworks for Object detection or machine learning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a broad question regarding machine learning and object detection. As places to start from, I would recommend general reading about `machine learning`, so as to become a little accustomed with the field, and I would also recommend you two check two of the most popular deep learning frameworks, namely [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/) and [PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/). For (mostly) non-deep learning based approaches, the first library I would suggest is [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org).

Then, you can dwell into an object detection algorithm like YOLO; here's a good [article](https://gilberttanner.com/blog/yolo-object-detection-with-keras-yolo3) about the algorithm using TensorFlow with keras.
Keep in mind though that I strongly advise you **not** to go straight to the algorithm if you 're completely new to machine learning, but to get a grasp of the bigger picture first.

Comment: Hi @Alex Metsai and thank you for the suggestions! For automatization in the industry of food, they use recognition and sensor for all this is quite used (for the moment, hard to check the technical aspects on internet), so would you say they use machine learning with those frameworks in order to process the production? Or they don't? I know too that currently to treat plastic waste they use recognition in movement, but I don't know what kind of tech they use specifically. Hard questions...

Comment: I'm quite positive that, yes, they do use machine learning for these tasks. Tensorflow is the go-to tool for production machine learning, and pytorch is quickly catching up. From my personal experience, a friend of mine is using machine learning for agricultural production, though I don't know specific details regarding frameworks etc.

Comment: Thanks again @Alex Metsai. Yes, the agriculture field is where I wanna use this tech, it is just a small project but it is gonna take some tech in the back of course ;) Thanks again for your suggestions.